# How can i upload video on specific youtube channel in iOS?

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

How can i upload video on specific youtube channel?
Currently every video i am uploading is uploaded on my channel only!
Please guide,thanks in advance

Comment: please provide info what u hav tried now?

Comment: I used this tutorial for uploading video on youtube using iphone.
 (https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS). I am successful to upload video on my own youtube channel, but my requirement is to upload it on one specific channel..I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: Have you guys found a solution for this one? I'm currently having the same problem too. I found out the API accepts channels.. but I don't know how to use it yet.